# How obvious is something affected by warp wood spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, equipment

The [warp wood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/warp-wood) spell allows you to change wooden objects so they can no longer fulfill their designed purpose. I am wondering just how obvious this needs to be.

In my case we are trying to leave a keep vulnerable to a hidden attacking army and it has siege weapons made of wood on top, and I am a druid. I was wondering if during the night or something I could ruin the siege weapons with warp wood but not have it obvious to the guards until they attempt to use it.

I expect that its clear there is something wrong from this line in the spell description

> You cause wood to bend and warp, permanently destroying its straightness, form, and strength

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read, there is no mention about this spell being subtle in the way it sabotages targets. It seems that the intended way to apply it is to use GM fiat on a case-by-case basis.

I get this conclusion from the list of examples included in the spell desciption:

> A warped door springs open (or becomes stuck, requiring a Strength check to open, at your option)

So the door will appear normal until you try to use it, then it's obvious. I guess anyone trying to examine it without using it would figure the trick.

> A boat or ship springs a leak.

This can typically be not obvious to notice, until the ship sinks. Then you can't not figure there was a leak.

> Warped ranged weapons are useless.

Useless is not only a malus, so I see this as for example a bow twisted in such a way that the string is not tight at all. Anyone with such a bow in his hands would notice the problem.

> A warped melee weapon causes a -4 penalty on attack rolls.

I don't think anyone would miss the fact that his lance is bent at 90°, but I guess it can be a bit more subtle like a weird handle that makes the weapon look like a different exotic weapon.

To sum up there are examples of not subtle uses of this spell, but no mention that using the spell makes the modification more obvious than modifying the item in a different way. You will have to think about the nature of the modification and how obvious it is.

About your specific case I am pretty sure it is easy to completely sabotage most of siege weapons by slightly altering a piece of wood in it (except for rams maybe). Of course if your enemy does a last minute check about eventual sabotages during the night it seems fair to have a skill opposition check (for example disable device vs knowledge(engineering)) for them to notice.

The spell wouldn't give you any advantage on your check, but it actually make it automatic to actually succeed in the sabotage, and quicker.